# automatically detect date columns when reading a file into a data.frame

Tags: r, date, read.table

When reading a file, the `read.table` function uses `type.convert` to distinguish between logical, integer, numeric, complex, or factor columns and store them accordingly.

I'd like to add dates to the mix, so that columns containing dates can automatically be recognized and parsed into `Date` objects. Only a few date formats should be recognized, e.g.

```
date.formats <- c("%m/%d/%Y", "%Y/%m/%d")
```

Here is an example:

```
fh <- textConnection(

 "num  char date-format1  date-format2  not-all-dates  not-same-formats
   10     a     1/1/2013    2013/01/01     2013/01/01          1/1/2013
   20     b     2/1/2013    2013/02/01              a        2013/02/01 
   30     c     3/1/2013            NA              b          3/1/2013"
)
```

And the output of

```
dat <- my.read.table(fh, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                     date.formats = date.formats)
sapply(dat, class)
```

would give:

```
num              => numeric
char             => character
date-format1     => Date
date-format2     => Date
not-all-dates    => character
not-same-formats => character   # not a typo: date format must be consistent
```

Before I go and implement it from scratch, is something like this already available in a package? Or maybe someone already gave it a crack (or will) and is willing to share his code here? Thank you.

Comment: Related to [Specify Date format for colClasses argument in read.table/read.csv](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13022299/271616).

Comment: Related, yes, and it can be useful to people researching this topic. In my case though, I need the date columns to be automatically detected.

Comment: by "same format" is it "exact format" or "ymd" order that is important (eg would '2013/01/01' and '2013-01-01' in the same column be ok?)

Comment: For my need, I prefer the exact same format as I assume the input files come from a trusted process. But for the sake of helping future visitors, feel free to bend the rules.

Comment: But can we convert "four score and seven years ago" to POSIXct?

Comment: Check out the `tryFormats` in `?as.POSIXct`.  That's a good list of string formats to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I threw one together quickly. It is not handling the last column properly because the `as.Date` function is not strict enough (see that `as.Date("1/1/2013", "%Y/%m/%d")` parses ok for example...)

```
my.read.table <- function(..., date.formats = c("%m/%d/%Y", "%Y/%m/%d")) {
   dat <- read.table(...)
   for (col.idx in seq_len(ncol(dat))) {
      x <- dat[, col.idx]
      if(!is.character(x) | is.factor(x)) next
      if (all(is.na(x))) next
      for (f in date.formats) {
         d <- as.Date(as.character(x), f)
         if (any(is.na(d[!is.na(x)]))) next
         dat[, col.idx] <- d         
      }
   }
   dat
}

dat <- my.read.table(fh, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
as.data.frame(sapply(dat, class))

#                  sapply(dat, class)
# num                         integer
# char                      character
# date.format1                   Date
# date.format2                   Date
# not.all.dates             character
# not.same.formats               Date
```

If you know a way to parse dates that is more strict around formats than `as.Date` (see the example above), please let me know.

**Edit**: To make the date parsing super strict, I can add

```
if (!identical(x, format(d, f))) next
```

For it to work, I will need all my input dates to have leading zeroes where needed, i.e. `01/01/2013` and not `1/1/2013`. I can live with that if that's the standard way.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `lubridate::parse_date_time`, which is a bit stricter (and creates `POSIXlt`) data.

I've also added a bit more checking for existing NA values (may not be necessary).

eg

```
library(lubridate)
my.read.table <- function(..., date.formats = c("%m/%d/%Y", "%Y/%m/%d")) {
  dat <- read.table(...)
  for (col.idx in seq_len(ncol(dat))) {
    x <- dat[, col.idx]
    if(!is.character(x) | is.factor(x)) next
    if (all(is.na(x))) next
    for (format in date.formats) {
      complete.x <- !(is.na(x))
      d <- as.Date(parse_date_time(as.character(x), format, quiet = TRUE))
      d.na <- d[complete.x]
      if (any(is.na(d.na))) next
      dat[, col.idx] <- d         
    }
  }
  dat

}

 dat <- my.read.table(fh, stringsAsFactors = FALSE,header=TRUE)

str(dat)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ num             : int  10 20 30
 $ char            : chr  "a" "b" "c"
 $ date.format1    : Date, format: "2013-01-01" "2013-02-01" "2013-03-01"
 $ date.format2    : Date, format: "2013-01-01" "2013-02-01" NA
 $ not.all.dates   : chr  "2013/01/01" "a" "b"
 $ not.same.formats: chr  "1/1/2013" "2013/02/01" "3/1/2013"
```

An alternative would be to use `options(warn = 2)` within the function and wrap the `parse_date_time(...)` in a try statement

```
my.read.table <- function(..., date.formats = c("%m/%d/%Y", "%Y/%m/%d")) {
  dat <- read.table(...)
  owarn <-getOption('warn')
  on.exit(options(warn = owarn))
  options(warn = 2)
  for (col.idx in seq_len(ncol(dat))) {
    x <- dat[, col.idx]
    if(!is.character(x) | is.factor(x)) next
    if (all(is.na(x))) next
    for (format in date.formats) {
      d <- try(as.Date(parse_date_time(as.character(x), format)), silent= TRUE)

      if (inherits(d, 'try-error')) next
      dat[, col.idx] <- d         
    }
  }
  dat

}
```

Comment: @flodel -- i've just added an option using `try` instead of the `any(is.na(...))` bit.

Comment: and the benefit is it will exit as soon as it can't parse a date? so faster overall?

Comment: @flodel `parse_date_time` isn't particularly fast in general (so while there may be some speed ups, the engine may be slower).  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645815/why-are-lubridate-functions-so-slow-when-compared-with-as-posixct for more discussion (and perhaps appproaches that may help)

Answer (score 1):

You can try with regular expressions.

```
my.read.table <- function(..., date.formats = c("%m/%d/%Y", "%Y/%m/%d")) {
   require(stringr)
   formats <- c(
     "%m" = "[0-9]{1,2}",
     "%d" = "[0-9]{1,2}",
     "%Y" = "[0-9]{4}"
   )
   dat <- read.table(...)
   for (col.idx in seq_len(ncol(dat))) {
      for (format in date.formats) {
         x <- dat[, col.idx]
         if(!is.character(x) | is.factor(x)) break
         if (all(is.na(x))) break
         x <- as.character(x)
         # Convert the format into a regular expression
         for( k in names(formats) ) {
           format <- str_replace_all( format, k, formats[k] )
         }
         # Check if it matches on the non-NA elements
         if( all( str_detect( x, format ) | is.na(x) ) ) {
           dat[, col.idx] <- as.Date(x, format)
           break
         }
      }
   }
   dat
}

dat <- my.read.table(fh, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
as.data.frame(sapply(dat, class))
#                  sapply(dat, class)
# num                         integer
# char                      character
# date.format1                   Date
# date.format2                   Date
# not.all.dates             character
# not.same.formats          character
```