# How to read CSV file with dates like YYYY-MM-DD and time like YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS?

Tags: r, date, datetime, csv

I have a csv file with the content like below:

```
VA1,VA2,2014-05-24,,2014-05-22 15:50:16
VA2,VA1,2014-05-24,2014-05-26,2014-05-22 15:50:16
```

How can I read it?
Standard `read.csv` can not recognize dates YYYY-MM-DD. I've tried to use `read.zoo`, but I am not sure how to:

1. indicate that two different formats of date & time are used: YYYY-MM-DD and YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS;
2. indicate that empty values are possible.

Here is what I've tried:

```
library(zoo)
colClasses <- c("factor", "factor", "Date", "Date", "Date")
fmt <- "%Y-%m-%d"
z <- read.zoo("file.csv", header = FALSE, sep = ",", quote = "", format = fmt, tz = "", colClasses = colClasses)
```

Comment: Possible dupe of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022299/specify-date-format-for-colclasses-argument-in-read-table-read-csv) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390674/automatically-detect-date-columns-when-reading-a-file-into-a-data-frame). However, perhaps `fread` + `fasttime` is faster than a `read.table/zoo` hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `read.zoo` to read that sort of data.  Its meant for time series.  Try the following.  No packages needed.  The code below has been written to be self contained but the `text = Lines` part could be replaced with the filename, e.g. `read.table("myfile.dat", ...whatever...)`:

```
Lines <- "VA1,VA2,2014-05-24,,2014-05-22 15:50:16
VA2,VA1,2014-05-24,2014-05-26,2014-05-22 15:50:16"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, sep = ",", as.is = TRUE, na.strings = "")
transform(DF, V3 = as.Date(V3), V4 = as.Date(V4), V5 = as.POSIXct(V5))
```

giving:

```
   V1  V2         V3         V4                  V5
1 VA1 VA2 2014-05-24       <NA> 2014-05-22 15:50:16
2 VA2 VA1 2014-05-24 2014-05-26 2014-05-22 15:50:16
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to read the table with `read.csv` and then set column 3 and 4 to date and datetime objects with `strptime`:

For column 3:

```
data[,3] = as.POSIXct(as.character(data[,3]))
```

For column 4:

```
data[,4] = as.POSIXct(as.character(data[,4]))
```

Comment: Thanks. But it returns the following warning - `Warning
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , "mycolumnname", value = list(sec = c(NA_real_,  : suggested 11 variables to replace 1 variable` (not sure about exact En translation since my R returns errors in local lang). In result values are converted to `numeric`. But the same code with `as.Date` works well and returns `Date`.

Comment: OK, my bad, doesn't work like the with strptime as the object it creates is a list. I'm updating the answer to something that works