# How to convert yyyy-mm-dd to day of the year in R?

Tags: r, date

I am trying to convert my data into different date format.

e.g from 2010-12-31 to 2010365

I tried code below but it gave me something different (e.g  359 360 361 362 363 364 365). 
I have my data from year 2000 to 2010.

```
dayofyear <- strptime(date, format="%Y-%m-%d")$yday + 1
```

Could somebody help please?

Many thanks.

Comment: opss...yup. Apologise for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
d <- as.POSIXlt("2010-12-31", format="%Y-%m-%d")
d$yday + 1
# 365
paste0(1900 + d$year, d$yday + 1)
# 2010365
```

Update: to read from txt file:

```
t <- read.table(file = "file.txt", header = TRUE, sep = ";", dec = ",") 
    # make settings according to file format
```

Then you can access the column value by `t$column_name` or `t[,column_number]`, and you replace the "2010-12-31" by one of these expressions and that's it.

Comment: Thanks @Tomas. Trying to figure out how to call a txt file into the code because all the dates from 2000-01-01 to 2010-12-31 is in a txt file form. By the way, 2010-12-31 should be 2010365. :)

Comment: the POSIXlt standard is 0 based indexing rather than 1 based, so 2010-01-01 is the 0th day of the year.

Comment: @Sofea reading from text file is very easy, updated my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tomas. You forgot to edit the second line which should also appear as d$yday+1. I have double check the leap years and all is correct.

Comment: Great Sofea, glad to help!

Answer (score 18):

In base r:

```
format(as.Date('2010-12-31'), format='%Y%j')
```

Or:

```
strftime('2010-12-31', format='%Y%j')
```

Answer (score 5):

```
library(lubridate)
date <- ymd("2010-12-31")
paste0(year(date), yday(date))
# [1] "2010365"
```

Comment: It's possible without installing a new library, see my answer.

Comment: @Tomas, Cheers, yes I am aware of that. It's just my personal preferences - I'm very pragmatic when it comes to using non-base packages or not. Sometime speed of execution is most important, sometimes time of writing/remembering the syntax ([see e.g. here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645815/why-are-lubridate-functions-so-slow-when-compared-with-as-posixct/10653798#10653798)). But thanks for reminding me of my (bad) habits ;)